# How to print 'flags' field in 'struct page' in Linux-based user program

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Hi,

I am trying to write a user program to print the value of the 'flags' field of all the pages in the 'mem_map' array. I then want to see if the reserved bit is set.

For starters, I wrote a kernel module to print the value of the first 20 pages in the 'mem_map' array, their respective 'flags' fields and the output of the PageReserved macro.

```
for (;i < 20; ++i) {
  unsigned long *value = &(mem_map[i].flags);
  printk("i = %u page->flags value = %u phy address = %#x isReserved = %d\n", i,mem_map[i].flags, virt_to_phys(&(mem_map[i].flags)),PageReserved(&mem_map[i]));
}
```

When I run "dmesg | tail -50", I see the following values:

```
[ 2858.387520] i = 0 page->flags value = 0    phy address = 0x36840000 isReserved = 0
[ 2858.387520] i = 1 page->flags value = 1024 phy address = 0x36840020 isReserved = 1
[ 2858.387520] i = 2 page->flags value = 1024 phy address = 0x36840040 isReserved = 1
[ 2858.387520] i = 3 page->flags value = 1024 phy address = 0x36840060 isReserved = 1
```

Note that I am printing the Physical address of the 'flags' field along with the value.

I want to reproduce the above result in a user program by just looking at the addresses via pointers.

I opened '/dev/mem', with the offset of the first page's 'flag' field: 0x36840000 . I made sure I compiled the kernel with STRICT_DEVMEM off and added a default 'return 1' in 'devmem_is_allowed()' function.

```
 /* create the offset for mmap() using the physical address of the
    mem_map[] array*/
    off_t offset = 0x36840000;

    /* /dev/mem contains the physical memory map */
    if ((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        printf("/dev/mem could not be opened.\n");
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    else {
        printf("/dev/mem opened.\n");
    }

    starting_page = (char*)mmap(0, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED, fd,offset);

    if (starting_page == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        return -1;
    } 
    else {
        printf("Memory mapped at address %p.\n", starting_page);
    }
    mapped_page = starting_page;
    for (i=0;i<10;++i,mapped_page+=32) { 
        printf("\npage i = %u flags value %ul  ", i, *(mapped_page));
    }
```

However, when I simply print out the value of the "flags value" ,I get zeros.  Any suggestions on what I am getting zeroes and how to debug this?

Thanks!
-RR

Comment: Did you just try to read `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/self/map_files/` ? You probably don't need any kernel module!

Comment: no I haven't. I want to learn how to access the page flags information in a user program. Since 'mem_map' is valid and available to me, it should be possible to access its contents via addresses & pointers. That is the point of my experiment.

Comment: It looks like mapped_page is a pointer to unsigned long int?  If so,  your pointer arithmetic is skipping 32 longs rather than 32 bytes.

Comment: 'mapped_page' is declared as a char* and hence incrementing it by 32 should be correct to go to the next page in the 'mem_map' array. Since 'flags' is the first field in 'struct page', 'mapped_page' might be already pointing to the 'flags' field. Hence, tried to print 'flags' by using %u printf modifier. Guess that didn't work...

Comment: forgot to add, on my 32 bit machine, the size of 'struct page' is 32 bytes. hence +=32 increment to 'mapped_page'.

Comment: Try printf("\npage i = %u flags value %ul  ", i, *((unsigned long *)(mapped_page)));

Comment: I was not able to get mmap to work but got 'lseek' + 'read' to work. I am printing which pages are reserved.                              if ((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
    printf("/dev/mem could not be opened.\n");
    perror("open");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    printf("/dev/mem opened.\n");
  }
 
  for (j=0,i=0;i< NUM_PHYSPAGES;++i,j += STRUCT_PAGE_SIZE) {
    lseek(fd, offset+j, SEEK_SET);
    n = read(fd, buf, PAGE_FLAGS_BYTES);
    printf("page %u flags value = %u isReserved = %d\n",i,*(unsigned long*) buf, (*(unsigned long*) buf & (1UL << 10))!=0  );
  }